# Split lines and substitute missing fields

Tags: text-processing, awk

Does anyone know how can I "split" the lines bellow (it is just an example):

```
mercedes|$40000|black|$42000|white|$41000|red
audi|$31000|blue|$10000|white
mercedes|$5000|blue
```

The output I expect is:

```
mercedes|$40000|black
mercedes|$42000|white
mercedes|$41000|red
audi|$31000|blue
audi|$10000|white
mercedes|$5000|blue
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problem. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with (`awk` seems to be your tool of choice), and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work. Also, please clarify how to determine the "expected" number of data fields per record. Currently it looks as if you are expecting three fields per line where the first can be missing - but could it be more complex (i.e. the first two missing, and only the changing 3rd specified?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `awk` script to output pairs of fields from each line from the 2nd field on, prefixing each outputted pair with the 1st field on the line.

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i = 2; i+1 <= NF; i += 2) print $1, $i, $(i+1) }' file
mercedes|$40000|black
mercedes|$42000|white
mercedes|$41000|red
audi|$31000|blue
audi|$10000|white
mercedes|$5000|blue
```

This assumes that the input conforms to expectations, which is that the final data should be organized into three columns.  This means   that the input is expected to strictly follow

```
title|pair 1a|pair 1b|pair 2a|pair 2b|...|pair Na|pair Nb
```

Comment: @Kusalananda `for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2)` gives same result.

Comment: Nice solution. `i+1 <= NF` is IMHO clearer written as `i < NF`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, possibly. Looping over every field is usually done with `i <= NF` where `i` will take the value of the largest field number (i.e. it's `i` that loops to `NF`).  In my loop, `i+1` loops up to `NF`. Yes, it's the same as `i < NF`, but then the condition becomes detached from the way I use `i` in the loop body. It's a tiny bit like documenting the loop with the code.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh It does, but `i` will never take the value `NF`. It's `i+1` that will be equal to `NF` in the last iteration.

Comment: @Kusalananda maybe make it `for (i = 3; i <= NF; i += 2) print $1, $(i-1), $i` if you find having the condition be `<= NF` clearer than using `i < NF`? I'm personally not a fan of executing `i+1` in the condition every time around the loop both from clarity and performance viewpoints but it's no big deal either way,

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` program will do this. You can pass the desired number of fields per line (in your case 3) as variable `nf` to the program.

```
awk -v nf=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
             NF==nf {print;next}
             {
                hd=$1;
                for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
                  if ((i-2)%(nf-1)==0) {printf "%s%s",hd,OFS}
                  printf "%s%s",$i,((i-1)%(nf-1)==0)?ORS:OFS
                }
             }' file
mercedes|$40000|black
mercedes|$42000|white
mercedes|$41000|red
audi|$31000|blue
audi|$10000|white
mercedes|$5000|blue
```

This will check if the line needs splitting. If the line only contains `nf` fields anyway (`NF` is the built-in field counter for the current line), it prints it unchanged.

Otherwise:

- It stores the first field in the variable `hd` (for "header").
- It then iterates over all "data" fields and prefixes the output with the `hd` field, followed by `nf-1` fields from the input, and then all over again until the line is processed.

  This is done by checking if the distance of the current field `i` to the first "data" field (field number 2) is an integer multple `nf`, and printing the `hd` field only then. The same kind of logic used to decide whether to print a field separator (`OFS`, set to `|` in the begin) to continue the line, or a record separator (`ORS`, defaults to newline) to start a new line.

This assumes that your lines only contain an integer multiple of `nf-1` fields plus one; no safeguards are included.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'[|]' '{ for(i=3; i<NF; i+=2) sub($i, $i ORS $1) }1' infile
```

note that first argument to the [*`sub(regexp, replacement [, target])`* function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is the *regex* so it will treat the `$i` as the *regex*.

see also more about [‘\’ and ‘&’ with sub(), gsub(), and gensub() functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html) when it comes to the second argument to these functions too.

---

Or alternatively, do as following without having those above issues with the sub():

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } { for(i=3; i<NF; i+=2) $i= $i ORS $1 }1' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

`python` in conjunction with the `itertools` module to repeatedly supply the first field for padding to the first two fields.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
import itertools as it
ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofs = fs = "|"
with open(ifile) as f:
  for l in f:
    L = l.rstrip("\n").split(fs)
    for a,b in zip(it.repeat(L.pop(0)),zip(*[iter(L)]*2)):
      print(a,*b,sep=ofs)
' file
```

---

`perl` can be used as well where we print leading 2nd+3rd fields along with the first and then the 2nd and 3rd are deleted, thus allowing the next ones to take their place.

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane '$,="|";
  print $F[0], splice(@F,1,2)
    while @F > 3;
  print @F;
' file
```

---

`GNU sed` with extended regex mode enabled `-E`.

- Mark till the end of third field in preparation to print from field 1 to 3.
- copy over the first field right after the third field in preparation for the next round of printing.

```
sed -Ee '
  s/[|]/\n/3;P
  s/^([^|]+[|]).*\n/&\1/;D
' file
```

Explanation:

- Visualize a line like this:

  - Car_brand | p1 | c1 | p2 | c2 | ... | on | cn
- We want the brand paired with price/color tuples on a line by itself.
- Replace the third pipe delimiter by a newlines: `s/[|]/\n/3`
- Visualize the pattern space now:

  - Car_brand | p1 | c1 \n p2 | 2 | ... | on | cn
- The sed command `P` (uppercase pee) prints to stdout  up to the first newline.
- Output till this stage is:

  - Car_brand | p1 | c1
- The use of the first pair of price / color is over. Now what needs to be done is copy over the car brand to the next price / color pair:

  - `s/^([^|]+[|]).*\n/&\1/`
  - the brackets remember the matched contents, which are: the leading data including the first pipe delimiter. And we match till the newline. The replacement is matched portion (&) appeNded with what we remembered (the car brand  |).
  - the pattern space now looks like
    Car_brand | p1 | c1 \n Car_brand | p2 | c2 | ... | l pn | cn
- The **D**elete command rips off till the first newline

  - pattern space now becomes
    Car _brand | p2 | c2 | .. | pn | cn
- The property of the `D` command is that after removing till the first newline and provided something remains it reapplies the sed code to the remaining pattern space.
- In short, this is equivalent to a looping action.

---

Result:

```
mercedes|$40000|black
mercedes|$42000|white
mercedes|$41000|red
audi|$31000|blue
audi|$10000|white
mercedes|$5000|blue
```

Comment: is possible explain more detailed the solution using sed? It was advanced

Comment: I have added a brief explanation of how the sed code works. Hope you find it clear and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -F"\|" -le '$,="|";
for (my $a=1;$a<@F;$a+=2) 
{print $F[0],$F[$a], $F[$a+1]}' input
```

- `-F"\|"` Input field separator set to `|`
- `$,="|";` Output field separator set to `|`
- `$a<scalar @F;` Here `scalar @F` tells total number of fields
  and `$a<scalar @F` because fields in perl start from zero.

This is [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655166/469418) by @Kusalananda but in `perl`.

Comment: You can remove the scalar before @F and make the $a variable lexical  in order to limit it's scope to within the for loop.

Comment: @guest_7 Thanks for upvote and editing.